# Reflexive Graded Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_d]$ be a polynomial ring and $M=M_0\oplus M_1\oplus M_2\oplus\cdots$ be a graded $R$-module. Is it true that $M$ is reflexive as an $R$-module if and only if $M_i$ is reflexive as an $R$-module for every $i$?

Comment: $M_i$ is a module over what? $k$? Vector spaces are reflexive.

Comment: As I said, even in the case where $R_0=k$, a field, in which case all the $M_i$ s are obviously reflexive (for a finitely generated module, so that these are finite dimensional vector spaces), $M$ may not be reflexive as an $R$-module.